# How to call Method In the Background even when the App got killed

Tags: java, android

```
public void PowerAction(){
    String messageToSend = "this is a message for helpppppppp!!!";
    String number = "+919999999999";   //strServerUrl+","+strServerUrl1;
    String number1 = "tel:" + "+919999999999".toString().trim();

    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null, null);
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number1, null, messageToSend, null, null);

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number1));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

I want to call this power action in the background even when the app has been killed, Right now I am calling this using Button click & when the user have Shake his device it works, when the app is in running state,but I want to perform this task in the background.

Comment: Read [Background tasks](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html).

Comment: Use service for this

Answer (score 0):

Use service to run a task when the app is in the background, but Android operating system will deliberately kill the service after some time for battery optimizations introduced from Android 6.0 called as Doze mode

But still there are hacks to create continuosly running background services

1. Using high priority alarms every few minutes and check if the
   service is running and start if the service has stopped.
2. Using FCM
   that will wakeup up the application, but it requires internet
3. You can attach a bubble just like facebook messenger popup and bind it to the background service which also gets killed when the service is killed, this makes sure if the background service is in existence easily without using adb shell

Read about the [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)